# How to change pydocumentdb request size limit?

Tags: python, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to send date to azure documentdb and I have to send a huge document (100 000+ lines), however when I send it I get a **Request size is too large error**.

I guess it should be possible to change this request size limit (which should be stored in a variable somewhere) but I can't find it, does someone know this ?

Thanks !

(I'm using pydocumentdb by the way)

Answer (score 0):

DocumentDB allows only documents upto 2MB to be sent/inserted. What's the size of your document and how complex/nested it is?

Comment: I don't know its size but I'm pretty sure it's over 2MB, I thought I could change this limitation but apparently i can't, I'll try an other way

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you got the error as below from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/http-status-codes-for-documentdb), when using pydocumentdb which wrappered the related REST APIs for DocumentDB. So I tried to reproduce the error successfully.

> **413 Entity Too Large**: The document size in the request exceeded the allowable document size for a request. The max allowable document size is 2MB.

I reviewed the REST API [`Create Document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/create-a-document), there is not any parameter or request header can change this limitation.

Comment: Oh ok, i thought there was one... I suppose i have to send my document parts by parts...

Comment: @polopolopolo What means to parts by parts? Do you want to create a document which size less than 2MB as a part, then to update the other part? If so, it will not work, because there is not a method `update` for a document, only a method [`replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/replace-a-document).